# C# generating and downloading PDF file not working

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm trying to generate and then download PDF file from a simple form.
I've got 2 options for users:
1. Generate and download directly after filling the form
2. Generate and download the saved documents.

The first one works perfectly, but the second case has a problem.
I'm using ajax to call the Download action:

```
function complaintDownload(object) {
    var id = object.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: '/Lawyers.AppPortal/Statement/Download',
        data: { id: id}
    });
}
```

Here's my action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public FileContentResult Download(int id)
    {
        var statement = Engine.Get<Statement>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
        var pdfModel = statement.ToStatementPdfModel();
        var path = BLL.PdfGenerator.Generate(pdfModel);
        var pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        return File(pdfBytes, "Application/pdf", "test.pdf");
    }
```

When I call this action nothing happens.

Comment: You can't download a file with Ajax.

Comment: Doing it as an ajax request is probably not the right method to achieve what you want here. Instead of an ajax request, try using a traditional form post to the action URL.

Comment: I want to retrieve data from database and then generate the file. That's the main problem.

Comment: Remove the `[HttpPost]` and just use a link to call the method and download the file

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and did the trick. Thanks!